# Post back variable from PHP to JS after POST?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to post from a PHP file to a JS to a PHP and get the results from the external PHP file to the JS file that posted the information? I don't what to get back that it's a success - I want to get what's echoed from the actual content from the PHP file that processes it.

Here's the code that I have:

```
$(function() {
$(".deletebutton").click(function() {

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "*****/process_delete.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {
      // Get results from form here
  }
 });
return false;
});
});
```

Haven't found anywhere where this is possible, is it? If so, please post some example code!

Thanks!
Coulton

Comment: Are you asking if you can get some data back from `process_delete.php` when you make a `POST` request to it? Yes - you can send back data in the `response` just like you would for a `GET`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, so this comes as a comment: check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for some options - I use json to get anything I want (as a result) from PHP, and display messages, check if success or failure, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`success`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function receives the data that the server returned as its first parameter

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "*****/process_delete.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function(data) {
      // do something with data here
  }
 });
```

You can use the `dataType` attribute of your `$.ajax` object to ensure you get the data back in the format you expect.  So if process_delete.php is returning JSON, for example:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "*****/process_delete.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function(data) {
      // do something with data here
  },
  dataType: "json" // The data string will be returned as a JavaScript object.
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your success callback to look like this:

```
success: function (data) {
   // data = the response from the server
}
```

Or am I misunderstanding the question?

**EDIT**

I think I see you mentioned that you're using JSON as well. If you want jQuery to automatically parse the response text into a JavaScript Object, then add `dataType: "json"` to your `$.ajax` configuration.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "*****/process_delete.php",
   data: dataString,
   dataType: "json", // or use "text json" if that doesn't work
   success: function() {
       // Get results from form here
   }
});
```

Comment: That's my question! Sorry if it sounded confusing! I'm trying your code out right now...